# MySQL Union After Select

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to insert rows into a temporary table after creating it via `SELECT` statement in MySQL?
I have this query that works as expected:

```
SELECT goldusers_user_ci.user_id, goldusers_users.username, goldusers_user_ci.contact_value
FROM goldusers_users
INNER JOIN goldusers_user_ci
ON goldusers_users.id = goldusers_user_ci.user_id
ORDER BY user_id
```

The idea is to select this query as a temporary table and add one row to it, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT goldusers_user_ci.user_id, goldusers_users.username, goldusers_user_ci.contact_value
FROM goldusers_users
INNER JOIN goldusers_user_ci
ON goldusers_users.id = goldusers_user_ci.user_id
ORDER BY user_id
) AS DBusers
INSERT INTO DBusers(user_id,username)
VALUES(-1,"All")
```

However, I get a syntax error. Is there any way to do this?

**Edit:
I believe I actually need to do a union after the select:
***the issue is the placement of the `ORDER BY` statement. Moving it to the bottom works

```
SELECT goldusers_user_ci.user_id, goldusers_users.username, goldusers_user_ci.contact_value
FROM goldusers_users
INNER JOIN goldusers_user_ci
ON goldusers_users.id = goldusers_user_ci.user_id
UNION ALL
SELECT -1 as user_id, "All" as username, "" as contact_value
ORDER BY user_id
```

Comment: The syntax is `INSERT INTO tablename (columns...) SELECT ....`

Comment: See the documentation for [`INSERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html)

Comment: `AS DBusers` doesn't create a temporary table.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, maybe I do not need a temporary table. I am looking to add one row to the query after the select statements.

Comment: Then use `UNION`.

Comment: Your first query contains 3 columns, but your added row only has 2 columns. They need to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT * 
INTO #TempTable
FROM(
        SELECT goldusers_user_ci.user_id, goldusers_users.username, goldusers_user_ci.contact_value
        FROM goldusers_users
        INNER JOIN goldusers_user_ci
        ON goldusers_users.id = goldusers_user_ci.user_id
        
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT -1, 'All', ''
) AS DBusers

SELECT *
FROM #TempTable

DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't use `#` before temporary table names.

Comment: yeah my bad. Create a table first, replace #TempTable with the table.

Comment: MySQL doesn't use `FROM` in `INSERT INTO` statements.

Comment: It seems like you're giving the SQL-Server answer.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test what you want, but base on your query, I think you want to Insert data after select data.

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT goldusers_user_ci.user_id, goldusers_users.username, goldusers_user_ci.contact_value
FROM goldusers_users
INNER JOIN goldusers_user_ci
ON goldusers_users.id = goldusers_user_ci.user_id
ORDER BY user_id
) AS DBusers;
INSERT INTO DBusers(user_id,username)
VALUES(-1,"All");
```

I think you just need to add semicolon `;`

Comment: The first query above works without the semicolon, but adding the semicolon to the second does not solve the issue.

Comment: @marksy95 The semicolon is needed to show where the first query ends and the second query starts.